# MS-Access Form - Populate Input Box based on multiple List Boxes

Tags: ms-access, vba

I have a form with multiple list boxes that all pull from the same table. I want a separate input box to populate a field from the table based on a selection from either list box. So if I select an item in MyListBox1 that record will display in the input box, but then if I select an item in MyListBox2, the input box will display that record instead.

I have a general idea how to do this with 1 list box based on the .selected of the MyListBox object. However, I'm trying to get an idea if its possible for based an Input box off the selected object's selection? Or last selected object if that makes sense.

Comment: Doesn't make sense to me. How can an 'input box' both display a record and populate a field? Usually a user enters value into 'input box' and that value is saved in record.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a really counter-intuitive interface, but assuming I've correctly understood what you are looking to achieve, I believe you would need to use an unbound Text Box which would be populated via the `After Update` event of each List Box.

For example, given two List Boxes respectively called `List1` & `List2`, and a Textbox called `Text1`, the following simplistic event handler could be defined for each list box to populate the Text Box accordingly:

```vb
Private Sub List1_AfterUpdate()
    Text1 = List1
End Sub
Private Sub List2_AfterUpdate()
    Text1 = List2
End Sub
```

Yielding the following daft behaviour:

[image]

Comment: Oh my that is a simpler approach than what I was thinking. And yes the interface with multiple boxes is totally not intuitive. I need to maintain it for a client and just add this feature. Thank I will give this a try tomorrow and let you know if it works.